# YouCompleteMe: Autocompletion triggered while typing (suggestion inserted without using TAB)

Tags: python, macvim, youcompleteme

When I'm typing, YouCompleteMe automatically inserts the suggestions without me pressing TAB. This results in stuff like `selflf` when I'm typing `self`, or me not being able to write `file` anymore, because YouCompleteMe will automatically insert a function from my file, `fill_jacobian`. From the YouCompleteMe readme I figured that the plugin should not behave like that. Am I doing something wrong? My `~/.vimrc` looks as follows:

```vimrc
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Avoid a name conflict with L9
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
" Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'user/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}


" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

set nocompatible    " use vim defaults
set ls=2            " allways show status line
set tabstop=4       " numbers of spaces of tab character
set shiftwidth=4    " numbers of spaces to (auto)indent
set scrolloff=3     " keep 3 lines when scrolling
"set showcmd         " display incomplete commands
set hlsearch        " highlight searches
set incsearch       " do incremental searching
set ruler           " show the cursor position all the time
set visualbell t_vb=    " turn off error beep/flash
set novisualbell    " turn off visual bell
"set nobackup        " do not keep a backup file
set number          " show line numbers
set ignorecase      " ignore case when searching 
"set noignorecase   " don't ignore case
set title           " show title in console title bar
set ttyfast         " smoother changes
"set ttyscroll=0        " turn off scrolling, didn't work well with PuTTY
set modeline        " last lines in document sets vim mode
set modelines=3     " number lines checked for modelines
"set shortmess=atI   " Abbreviate messages
set nostartofline   " don't jump to first character when paging
set whichwrap=b,s,h,l,<,>,[,]   " move freely between files
"set viminfo='20,<50,s10,h

set autoindent     " always set autoindenting on
set smartindent        " smart indent
"set cindent            " cindent
"set noautoindent
"set nosmartindent
"set nocindent
set cinkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,e " default is: 0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e

"set autowrite      " auto saves changes when quitting and swiching buffer
set expandtab      " tabs are converted to spaces, use only when required
"set sm             " show matching braces, somewhat annoying...
"set nowrap         " don't wrap lines


syntax on           " syntax highlighing
if has("gui_running")
    " See ~/.gvimrc
    set guifont=Monospace\ 10  " use this font 
    set lines=50       " height = 50 lines
    set columns=100        " width = 100 columns
    set background=light   " adapt colors for background
    set selectmode=mouse,key,cmd
    set keymodel=
else
    "colorscheme elflord    " use this color scheme
    set background=light       " adapt colors for background
endif

if has("autocmd")
    " Restore cursor position
    au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0|if line("'\"") <= line("$")|exe("norm '\"")|else|exe "norm $"|endif|endif

    " Filetypes (au = autocmd)
    au FileType helpfile set nonumber      " no line numbers when viewing help
    au FileType helpfile nnoremap <buffer><cr> <c-]>   " Enter selects subject
    au FileType helpfile nnoremap <buffer><bs> <c-T>   " Backspace to go back

    " When using mutt, text width=72
    au FileType mail,tex set textwidth=72
    "au FileType cpp,c,java,sh,pl,php,phtml,asp  set autoindent
    au FileType cpp,c,java,sh,pl,php,phtml,asp,xml,javascript  set smartindent
    nnoremap <C-p> :set invpaste paste?<CR>
    set pastetoggle=<C-p>
    set showmode
    "au FileType cpp,c,java,sh,pl,php,phtml,asp  set cindent
    "au BufRead mutt*[0-9] set tw=72

    " Automatically chmod +x Shell and Perl scripts
    "au BufWritePost   *.sh             !chmod +x %
    "au BufWritePost   *.pl             !chmod +x %

    " File formats
    au BufNewFile,BufRead  *.phtml  set syntax=php
    au BufNewFile,BufRead  *.pls    set syntax=dosini
    au BufNewFile,BufRead  modprobe.conf    set syntax=modconf

    " Ctrl+X O
    autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
    autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
    autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
    autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
    autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
    autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
    autocmd FileType c set omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete
    autocmd FileType make set noexpandtab shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=0
    autocmd FileType php noremap <C-L> :!php -l %<CR>
    autocmd Filetype html,xml,xsl source ~/.vim/closetag.vim
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently some remaps in the `.vimrc` interfere with YouCompleteMe. See https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/783